# How to use linear algebra operations with Tensorflow C++ API?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am trying to link tensorflow as shared library to my c++ project, and want to call linear algebra operations such as "MatrixDeterminant" and "Qr" registed in `tensorflow/core/ops/linalg_ops.cc`. How should I properly do that?

Comment: Hi. Have you got any working code that you can show us you're stuck on and we can go from there.

Comment: @jackw11111 No, cuz I stuck on the very beginning. I didn’t see those operations in the API document.

Comment: There is a "hello world" for the C++ API here (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/cc). If you work on getting that up and running, I can look into the docs and see if I can find the right calls.

Comment: @jackw11111 thx, I think I figured out how to do it. Cuz the responsible header file is machine generated, located in bazel-genfiles. I overlooked that.

Comment: Okay. Yes I saw the `#include "tensorflow/cc/ops/linalg_ops.h` file included in `standard_ops.h`, from the example in the link, but thought something isn't adding when `tensorflow/cc/ops/` doesn't contain a `linalg_ops.h`, but makes sense that it would be generated during the build.